# regex code to remove Extra Spaces from begging of the line?

Tags: regex

regex code to remove Extra Spaces from begging of the line? i.e.:

```
john
 john123
johny@123
 john$123
marcelo 123
maria 1234
```

Output:

```
john
john123
johny@123
john$123
marcelo 123
maria 1234
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as per the [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) we are not allowed to help you with hacking. [word list updater](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+list+updater) is a tool used exclusively by the hacking community.

Answer (score 0):

With using sed:

```
sed -e 's/^[ ]*//'
```

Comment: i use Word List Updater 2.7 for windows so this code donsn't work for me

Comment: @MunteanCosmin You should have mentioned that in your question, along with what you've tried already, and what the results were.  That lack of shared info and research is (most likely) what's garnering you down-votes on your question.